# How can I use __chooseRandom with a URL parameter?

Tags: jmeter

**Context**: I want to use the __chooseRandom function to embed a randomly chosen value in a URI path.

**Problem**: I can't figure out how to use the __chooseRandom function properly. With the below example, the URL I get is 'https://google.com/search?q=&iter=${__chooseRandom(1111,2222,iter)}' instead of https://google.com/search?q=1111 or https://google.com/search?q=2222

**Question**: How should I modify the JMeter script so the request path gets a value from chooseRandom instead of directly embedding the chooseRandom string?

**Not Working Example**:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your problem properly you are trying to generate a random value at the end of that URL from a set of variables (numbers).

You can try to follow these steps:
add **User Defined Variables** -> Right click on **Test Plan** -> **Add** -> select **Config Element** -> **User Defined Variables**

Add following variables (Change values and variables names depending on your needs)

```
   Name:    Value:
    num1     111
    num2     222
    num3     333
    num4     444
```

Then all you have to do now is to use this ${__V(num${__Random(1,4,)})}

This function will actually get the value of each variable name that starts with "num" and ends with a random value between 1 and 4 (value of num1 = 111 , the value of num3 = 333 ...)

PS: I tried using this as a JSON parameter

**Body Data:**

```
{
    "iter" : ${__V(num${__Random(1,6,)})}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that URL path is being evaluated before request parameter.

You need to call the `__chooseRandom()` function either somewhere before the HTTP Request sampler or get rid of this `${iter}` variable and use `__chooseRandom()` function directly in the request path.

```
/search?q=${__chooseRandom(1111,2222,iter)}
```

Demo:
[image]

More information:

- [__chooseRandom() function documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#chooseRandomsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-0-1-font-sup)
- [How to Use the Custom JMeter Functions Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-custom-jmeter-functions-plugin)